# Weak Convergence in Hilbert Spaces & Inner Product

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, weak-convergence

I have a question about weak convergence in Hilbert spaces. Suppose we have a Hilbert space $H$ equipped with a scalar product $(\cdot / \cdot)$, and that in this space we have $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ for some $x \in H$.

Then I know that $\forall \lambda \in H^{*}$ we have $\lambda(x_n) \rightarrow \lambda(x)$, which by applying the Riesz representation theorem yields:

$$
(x_n / y) \rightarrow (x / y) \forall y \in H      \quad \quad           (1)
$$

**Question: is it true that $(x_k / x_l) \rightarrow (x/x) = ||x||^2$ as $k,l \rightarrow \infty$?**

**My proof idea**: I think this result is true.
Consider the quantity $R = (x/x) - (x_k / x_l)$. Add and take away $(x / x_l)$:

$$
R = [(x/x) - (x / x_l)] + [(x / x_l) - (x_k / x_l)]
$$

And both brackets go to 0 by letting $k,l$ go to $\infty$, by (1).
However I know we don't necessarily have that $(x_n / x_n) \rightarrow (x / x)$... I am not sure if this means the proof I gave is wrong or not...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think that you can just take each limit in turn: $(x_k, x_l) \to (x, x_l)$ as $k \to \infty$ and $(x, x_l) = \overline{(x_l, x)} \to \overline{(x, x)} = (x, x)$ as $l \to \infty$.

Comment: @JosephHarrison Double limit is different from an iterated limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general your claim is wrong. See that if you assume $(x_k,x_l) \rightarrow (x,x)$ you get with $k=l$ that
$$
||x_k||^2 = (x_k,x_k) \rightarrow (x,x) = ||x||^2.
$$
Now you may know that weak convergence plus convergence of the norm gives strong convergence, this is true in an arbitrary Hilbert space and it even holds in uniformly convex spaces. So for a sequence that converges weakly and not strongly your claim cannot hold.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. Can you explain why the proof that I proposed is wrong then? I feel like it should be obvious but I am not seeing it...

Edit: I have figured it out, I think. It is true that i can let one of the brackets go to 0, but then the convergence rate for the other bracket depends on the specific k or l i am at...

Comment: Yes you figured it out correctly and indeed $R$ vanished if and only if $(x_k,x_l) \rightarrow (x,x)$ so your trick actually does not make you win something.